# jQuery tabs are all displaying open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, but still I can't figure out what is wrong.  I had this working fine on my desktop, but can't get it to work live.  I've checked the paths and those seem to be fine.  For some reason the jQuery tabs section are all showing at once.  Also, the colorbox isn't working.

I'm getting errors from Colorbox stating that the function is not defined

I'm getting an error from jquery-1.11.0.min.js.2 which I'm not quite sure what the error is here.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Colorbox.js:6
(anonymous function) Colorbox.js:6
j jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
n.extend.ready jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
K
```

I'm also getting an error related to the admin-bar.min.jv?ver=3.9.3:1
and jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.1:29

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.9.1:1
a.fn.hoverIntent admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.9.1:1
(anonymous function) admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.9.1:1
b.extend.ready jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.1:29 & :37
u
```

**I added this link to my local file and sure enough it broke my page locally in the same way.**

```
<script type='text/javascript'        src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated because I don't know what to try and do to fix these errors. I've looked through my wordpress templates and the header, but I can't find where this link is coming from.  I'm wondering if Wordpress or another plugin is inserting it??

Comment: Wordpress includes jQuery by default, so most likely the issue is that jQuery is being called twice(2 different versions). You either need to remove your call to jQuery or override the default Wordpress version.

Comment: I've tried commenting out the jquery reference and the jquery ui reference, but then I get another error. I'm now getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"  It is referring to this function, "<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>"

Comment: The jQuery library included with Wordpress uses [no conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). You'll need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Thanks that worked.  One thing that I did have to do was move the jquery UI reference to the footer since Wordpress loads the jquery library after the header loads.  is that normal?  I don't think that the jQuery UI should be in the footer though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, here are the ways around the jQuery [no conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

You can use the word `jQuery` in place of `$` like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Using jQuery in place of $");
});
```

You can reassign the shortcut in the wrapper like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.content').html('Using $ WITHIN your function will now work')
});
```

Finally, you can set up a new shortcut through a variable like this:

```
var $j = jQuery;    
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.content').html('Using $j will now work in place of $')
});
```